# Some questions about wave operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

On sec. 3.4.1 in Schlag & Nakanish: invariant manifolds and dispersive Hamiltionian evolution equations, the authors talked something about wave operators. The wave operators are defined as the strong limits in $L^2$,
\begin{equation}
W= s- \lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-it H } e^{it H_0}, \quad H=-\Delta+V, \; H=-\Delta.
\end{equation}
And I have two questions about it.

- If W exists, then W is isometric on $L^2$. By the fact that $W$ is isometric, how can I check that $WW^*$ and $W^*W$ are projections, the former onto $Ran(W)$, the latter being the identity?
- Can we precisely know $Ran (W)$ if we just know $W$ exists? Does $Ran(W)= L_c^2$, where $L_c^2$ is the continuous subspace w.r.t. $H=-\Delta+V$? Or it requires more on $V$, e.g., should we add more restriction onto $V$, such as add more decay and regularity onto $V$?

Comment: For the first point, i guess it is a consequence of the Polar decomposition: $W=PV$ where $P$ is positive and $V$ a partial isometry (there is left or right version of that decomposition). Part of the theorem says that $VV^*$ and $V^*V$ are projections on some subspaces. Here $P$ is the identity and $W=V$. No idea for the 2nd point

Comment: [The linked section.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7a8AtzfIB6wC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=3.4.1+in+Schlag+%26+Nakanishi:+invariant+manifolds+and+dispersive+Hamiltonian+evolution+equations&source=bl&ots=DOqXgBeZCu&sig=ACfU3U3H9UFVmJqJ9xx0QuqmhMQdjXDKkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq8a7LidPpAhU3JDQIHegLAugQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=3.4.1%20in%20Schlag%20%26%20Nakanishi%3A%20invariant%20manifolds%20and%20dispersive%20Hamiltonian%20evolution%20equations&f=false)